# Github Actions not able to connect with docker swarm container

Tags: github-actions, docker-swarm

Running a test cases in Github action trying to connect with rabbitmq which is deployed on Docker Swarm, Its giving error Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error.

But if tried to connect rabbitmq (docker swarm) from my local machine, the same test case executed successfully.

Comment: Do you have specific login/proxy configuration for accessing your Swarm?

Comment: While connecting it from your GHA workflow, are you using its IP? Is that publicly available?

Comment: Others containers (kafka, influxdb) I am able to connect from GHA but not only rabbitmq

Comment: @Azeem Yes we are using docker swarm url and its publicly available

Comment: Did you try to check its connectivity from your GHA workflow e.g. using `ping`, `telnet`, `curl`, etc.?

Comment: Please include your relevant GHA workflow in your question along with the logs of that step which is failing.

Comment: @Azeem I cannot ping, telnet and curl as random port is getting generated for each run

Comment: @Azeem We have step (test) in GHA which is failing, during this step we are executing our integration test cases. All other containers I am able to connect from our test cases but while we try to create or bind queue in rabbitmq, its getting failed due to connection error. It means our test cases will not able to connect rabbitmq container